# How can I copy pdf files to the corresponding folders given in excel sheet?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pdf, directory

I am a beginner in python, I have a folder with lots of pdf files, I also have an excel file as shown below with the all the file names and corresponding folders to which the file has to be copied to. How can I do this using python?

| File_Name | Folder |
| --- | --- |
| a.pdf | alpha |
| b.pdf | beta |

I used shutil, but not sure how to use it to perform the task.

```
import shutil, os
import pandas as pd
root = 'pdf files path'

df = pd.read_excel('excel_file_path')

for x in df.File_Name:
    if x in root:
        shutil.copy(x, df.Folder)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the code implementation that you tried and the errors if any.

Answer (score 0):

```
from shutil import copyfile
copyfile(src, dst) # or copy if you want to copy directory
```

With this, you copy the src file to the dst directory

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, But can you tell me how it can be done for a list of files.

Comment: use the os module and the listidir methods.
You have to loop throug the directory with listdir
Check documentations or examples in the net